# Runtime Reflection Library for c++ that allow serialization and deserialization of custom types

Tags: c++, serialization, reflection, deserialization, metaprogramming

I'm looking for a library that allows to serialize and deserialize custom types in a few lines of code.

I've already tested this library [RTTR](https://www.rttr.org/), but unluckily it does not fit my purpose (also is poorly documented).

What I wish to achieve in pseudo-code is something like:

```
void serializeInstance(instance)
{
    for (property in instance)
    {
        serializeProperty("propertyName", property);
    }
}

void deserializeInstance()
{
    // Getting the type of the component from a string stored in a file
    type = getType(component["Type"]); 

    decltype(type) component;
    
    properties = getProperties(component["Properties"]);

    for (propertyName in properties)
    {
        // need to cast this to the right type
        component.property = getPropertyValue(propertyName["Value"]);
    }
}
```

To make it simple I'm trying to do something similar to what Unity does with the serialization of components.

This is a class diagram of my components: [ClassDiagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh6qS.png)
I wish to be able to deserialize from a Yaml file all my components.

YAML file:

```
Scene Object: 1252896902983049
    Component: Mesh
        Vertices: {...}
        Indices: {...}
        Path: ./Assets/Mesh/Cube.obj
```

.cpp file:

```
YAML::Emitter node;
// Storing Component Name in a string (in this case "Mesh")
std::string componentName = node["Scene Object"]["Component"].as<std::string>();


// Don't know how to do this so I'll paste some pseudo code

// This auto should return my Mesh component not an instance of IComponent
auto component = generateComponentFromComponentName(componentName);
// Get all the attributes in class component by name
foreach (attribute in component.getAttributes())
    // The cast to the attribute type is already implemented by me
    attribute = node["Scene Object"]["Component"][attribute.name()].as<attribute.type()>();
```

Comment: Unity uses `C#` which has runtime reflection.  C++ does not have runtime reflection.  You will either need to _"roll-your-own"_ using some form of class / property registration or take an  approach similar to [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) where the you define the serialisation format first and then generate the C++ code from that definition.

Comment: It seems to me `component` should be a parameter inside `void deserializeInstance` like this `void deserializeInstance(type& component)`

Comment: @RichardCritten Can you provide some references for an approach class/property registration? I've tried some solutions but the result wasn't satisfying. Also, I'll have a look at Protocol Buffers approach! I was wondering how to serialize things like Unity because I don't know Unreal Engine, I could take a look at their system too!

Comment: If you want to see how horrific it could be, to do what you're trying to do, take a look at how Avro is implemented in C, which I think comes close to a class / property registration system... Far better to either change language to one that supports reflection, or run with something that is resolved in the compiler such as Google Protocol Buffers, ASN.1, Boost serialisation,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oops library is doing what you are looking for. It is written for serialization using reflection.

https://bitbucket.org/barczpe/oops

You can find examples and some documentation on the wiki page.

I implemented the classes from your class diagram and added the type description or reflection to all classes.
It handles the yaml file for you. Your code does not need to deal with the yaml tree and connect the yaml nodes with the members of the classes.
This is all done by Oops. This is faster and simpler. Oops has its own yaml parser, and it does not build that immediate data-structure from the yaml file.
However, I do not recommend using yaml file format. It is not the best for serializing C++ objects.
Use the text format of the Oops library if you have a choice.
It is similar, but designed for storing C++ objects.

Here is the code (what you can also find in the AbstractClasses_test.cpp file of Oops unit test):

```
#include "SerializationTest.h"
#include <oops/Enum2StringTool.h>
#include <oops/rPropInterface.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <string>


using namespace rOops;

class IComponent
{
public:
    virtual ~IComponent() = default;
    IComponent() = default;
    virtual void init(short) = 0;
    rOOPS_ADD_PROPERTY_INTERFACE_ABSTRACT(IComponent)
    {
    }
};

DECLARE_ENUM_CLASS(CameraType, std::uint8_t,
    eNone = 0,
    eType1,
    eType2
);
rOOPS_DECLARE_ENUM_TYPE_INFO( CameraType, CameraType2String )

class Camera : public IComponent {
public:
    Camera() = default;
    void init(short p) override
    {
        height = width = p;
    }
private:
    CameraType type{CameraType::eNone};
    int height{0};
    int width{0};

    rOOPS_ADD_PROPERTY_INTERFACE(Camera)
    {
        rOOPS_INHERIT(IComponent);
        rOOPS_PROPERTY(type);
        rOOPS_PROPERTY(height);
        rOOPS_PROPERTY(width);
    }
};

rOOPS_DECLARE_STL_LIST_TYPE_INFO(std::vector<long>)

class Mesh : public IComponent
{
public:
    Mesh() = default;
    void init(short p) override
    {
        indices.push_back(p);
        path = std::to_string(p);
    }
private:
    std::vector<long> indices;
    std::string path;
    rOOPS_ADD_PROPERTY_INTERFACE(Mesh)
    {
        rOOPS_INHERIT(IComponent);
        rOOPS_PROPERTY(indices);
        rOOPS_PROPERTY(path);
    }
};

class ILight : public IComponent
{
public:
    ~ILight() override = default;
    ILight() = default;
    rOOPS_ADD_PROPERTY_INTERFACE_ABSTRACT(ILight)
    {
        rOOPS_INHERIT(IComponent);
    }
};

using Vec3 = std::array<double, 3>;
rOOPS_DECLARE_STL_ARRAY_TYPE_INFO(Vec3)

class PointLight : public ILight
{
public:
    PointLight() = default;
    void init(short p) override
    {
        AO[0] = Diffuse[1] = Specular[2] = p;
    }
private:
    Vec3 AO{};
    Vec3 Diffuse{};
    Vec3 Specular{};
    rOOPS_ADD_PROPERTY_INTERFACE(PointLight)
    {
        rOOPS_INHERIT(ILight);
        rOOPS_PROPERTY(AO);
        rOOPS_PROPERTY(Diffuse);
        rOOPS_PROPERTY(Specular);
    }
};

rOOPS_DECLARE_STL_LIST_TYPE_INFO(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IComponent>>)

TEST(AbstractClassesTest, IComponents)
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IComponent>> v;
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<Camera>()); v.back()->init(1);
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<Mesh>()); v.back()->init(2);
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<PointLight>()); v.back()->init(3);

    std::stringstream strm(cStringStreamMode);
    rOopsYamlFormat format(strm);
    save(format, v, "Components");
    std::cout << "========== save ==========" << std::endl;
    std::cout << strm.str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "==========================" << std::endl;

    rOopsYamlParser parser(strm, "Components");
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IComponent>> v2;
    load(parser, v2);
}
```

And here is the yaml file:

```
Components: !std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IComponent>>
  - !Camera&94841900126576
    IComponent:
    type: eNone
    height: 1
    width: 1
  - !Mesh&94841900120480
    IComponent:
    indices:
      - 2
    path: "2"
  - !PointLight&94841900126768
    ILight:
      IComponent:
    AO:
      - 3
      - 0
      - 0
    Diffuse:
      - 0
      - 3
      - 0
    Specular:
      - 0
      - 0
      - 3
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Is it possible to determine the type of the class stored in the file and instantiate it automatically? What I mean is `rOops::load(...)` into an instance of the type of the currently deserialized class. In the examples I see 

    `A a2;`
    `rOops::rOopsTextParser parser(strm_txt, "a");`
    `rOops::load(parser, aCopy);`


But I wish A to be determined at runtime!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. rOops::load() is just a simple wrapper around the TypeInfo load() function. Internally it does exactly what you want, but the question is, how the client program knows, what was loaded?
For example you can load polymorph classes to a unique pointer, or you can use the interface of the TypeInfo class for creating and loading the object: read the type name, get the TypeInfo, call createObj() for creating an object, and call load() for loading it.
Please, give me more details about your use-case for writing some example code for you.

Comment: I've added to the question above a link to an image that shows a class diagram for my problem, also I've added some extra pseudo code that hopefully explains my issue a bit better. Let me know if I was clear enough, thanks!

Comment: I added a simple implementation according to your class diagram. I hope this helps.